# Iptables to UFW before.rules not working

Tags: debian, iptables, ufw

I've got the follwing working iptables commands:

```
iptables -t nat -i ppp0 -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 81 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.16.8:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -t nat -i ppp0 -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.16.8:5000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 5000 -j MASQUERADE
```

I tried to add the following code to /etc/ufw/before.rules at the top and then at the bottom of the file, and did not work:

```
# NAT table rules
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

-A PREROUTING -i ppp0  -p tcp --dport 81 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.16.8:80
-A PREROUTING -i ppp0  -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.16.8:5000

:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

-A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 5000 -j MASQUERADE

COMMIT
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to write it like this?

```
# NAT table rules
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

-A PREROUTING -i ppp0  -p tcp --dport 81 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.16.8:80
-A PREROUTING -i ppp0  -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.16.8:5000

-A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 5000 -j MASQUERADE

COMMIT
```

The `:PREROUTING` and  `:POSTROUTING` policies seems to need to be declared just after the `*nat` line. At least it is how it looks like in my personal iptables rules file.

Comment: Did not work, here is the iptables-save -c log: http://pastebin.com/sn3hBFuT

Comment: Hi, when you say "did not work", what kind of error do you get in return?

Comment: The port was unreachable from outside.